# Auto sized multi line text in a button

Tags: c#, .net, text, multiline, autosize

I have a button that needs the font size of the text to be changed based on how much text is in the button. This is changed dynamically during run-time.

Basically, the text needs to start fairly large, then it needs to test how much text is in the button and decide whether to go down in size or not. It could do this in a loop by decreasing the size by one, repainting, and testing each time to see if the text fits now. If not, loop again until it does.

But the problem is with testing it. The button has multi line text, and that's the way I want it. So I can't simply test the width of the text with the width of the button using something like TextRenderer.MeasureText, because that assumes the text will only be one line. It never measures based on if it can fit on two or more lines.

So if one line of text at a certain font is 40 pixels in height, even if its on 3 lines of text on the button, TextRenderer.MeasureText.Height will show 40 pixels. And with margins and padding on the button, and space between lines of text, I can't just do 40 * 3 to get how much 3 lines would be, it's not that simple.

So... how do I test whether or not the text in the button is too big for the button?

I could set Auto Ellipsis property to true, but there's no way to test to see if the Auto Ellipsis has been used or not. So that doesn't help.

I could set Auto Size to true and test to see if the button size changed, then bring it back to the right size and lower the text size, but, it resizes based on width, before it moves text to the second line, so it's always on one line. So that doesn't help.

Any ideas? I just want to auto size multi line text. It seems so simple.

Comment: What framework? WinForms? WebForms? WPF?...

Comment: Yous should state the framework, in WinForms I would use `Graphic.MeasureString`

Comment: Sorry, I thought it put this is a C# forum automatically. It's .NET and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solutions for this for Windows Forms:
Set the starting size on `TextBox` than the size will be changed by this event handler.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
    {
        Graphics g = textBox.CreateGraphics();
        var width = g.MeasureString("a", textBox.Font).Width;//Get One Symbol Width
        var totalWidth = width * textBox.Text.Length; // Calculate the width of the full text
        if(totalWidth<width*10) // do what you want depending on conditions
        {
            textBox.Font=new Font(textBox.Font.Name,20f);
        }
        else if(totalWidth < width * 20)
        {
            textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font.Name, 16f);
        }
        else if(totalWidth < width * 30)
        {
            textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font.Name, 14f);
        }
        else if (totalWidth < width * 40)
        {
            textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font.Name, 12f);
        }
        else if (totalWidth < width * 50)
        {
            textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font.Name, 10f);
        }
    }
}
```